# Is TCP Communication a 2-way communication?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, port, firewall, tcpclient

This is really a newbie question regarding TCP Communication.

Is TCP Communication a 2-way communication?

Let me give a scenario:
One program is listening to a TCP port, say port 25. An external program connects to the first program's IP address (port 25) with a random outgoing port, say port 45000

Since the first program is just listening, does that mean that

1. The first program can only receive data and not send back any data through Port 25?
2. If it can send data, what protects the second computer's outgoing port 45000 from malicious attacks from the first program through port 25? As I know correctly, Firewalls are only for Incoming Ports.

Any replies are highly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TCP is always 2-way. There is no 'send and forget' as with UDP. The first Program would have to open a Server Socket. This means, that it listens on port 25 for a TCP SYN (A flag, that signals that a connection is being opened). If your second program connects on port 25 (from port 45000), that connection is identified by 4 values, IP of your host, Port of your host, IP of the remote host, Port of the remote host. At this moment, where the 3-Way handshake (SYN, SYN ACK, ACK) is done, the first program gets a client socket from the server socket returned, which is connected to your second program. So yes, as soon as the connection is made, it is a 2-way communication and you are vulnerable.

Firewalls mostly block incoming traffic. If your first program was behind a firewall, and had not configured the firewall correctly, the firewall would drop the SYN-Packets from the second program. No connection would be made. A firewall can also check outbound connections, if configured correctly.

As I said. As soon as you have connected to the remote program, the remote program gets a client socket, just like your local program, through which all communication is done.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation... so does this mean that the connecting client will be vulnerable? Is that why when we browse certain websites (port 80), we sometimes get a malicious warning from google not to go to that website? T

Comment: Ahm, yes and no. If you connect to google on port 80, the google web server accepts your client. Then, the server program returns a client socket, which is connected to your browser client socket. Then, your browser sends the "GET / HTTP/1.1" HTTP-Packet over the connection, which is read by the google side. Google then takes their website and sends it to you. Now is the point where malicious attacks can come into play. There are multiple vectors where you could be attacked. Someone could hijack your TCP Connection, someone could also inject malic. traffic into the google website (JavaScript)

Comment: I think what you meant was websites that show the red banner where google tells you not to go there. No, these websites do not exploit TCP connections. You connect there and they send you over that TCP connection malicious content. You go there, do the GET Part of HTTP and the website reponds with malicious code. TCP in is never under fire, but your browser, who parses the whole transaction (HTTP Part) so he can render the website is under fire.

Comment: Thanks again, your explanation is very good. So is it possible for TCP to be under fire through your outgoing ports? If yes, how do we protect our outgoing ports?

Comment: TCP is never really under fire actually. Mostly your TCP Stack is the structure which can be corrupted by maliciously crafted packets. As long as your client socket has a destination to connect to (like google), it is just fine. Only google can send you malicious code. As long as your OS handles TCP Packets correctly, there is no real need for worries about that. A firewall like Norton or Ashampoo or Kaspersky does a fine job too at protecting your machine from incoming connections. And if you are behind a NATed router, there are no incoming connections, only outgoing to websites you requested